# uuencode to attach all files in a directory

Tags: linux, unix, email, shell

I am using uuencode and mail to do basic file attachments to an email.

```
$ path/to/targetdir/audio.gsm audio.gsm | mail user@mail.com
```

This works but my problem is I am trying to find a way to recursively attach all files in `targetdir` from the example above.

I am familiar with some shell scripting basics so I wouldnt be opposed to a
solution using some shell scripting.

Thanks in advance for any help regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to the following:

```
(cd path/to/targetdir; tar czf - .) | uuencode archive.tar.gz | mail user@mail.com
```

The cd will change to the targetdir. The tar command will archive everthing in . (then the targetdir) and gzip it (option z) and write it to stdout (option f, "-" refers to stdout). uuencode with only one parameter reads its data from stdin instead of a file. The archive.tar.gz is the decode name.

Comment: This works really well. I appreciate the explanation of option flags too. Thanks